# How to create dynamic bar chart with values of X-axis and Y-axis in android

Tags: java, android, bar-chart

How to create a dynamic bar chart with values of X-axis and Y-axis in Android.

For example,consider the values of `(x,y) = (16,450),(40,200),(52,350)` and `(68,580)`, the graph should be plotted as per these values and these values should be mentioned in `X-axis` and `Y-axis`.

The above (x,y) values are just for sample. I have weekly and monthly and yearly analysis in the drop-down in my project. So, if I click weekly analysis in the drop-down, I will hit my API, get the values of (x,y) from it and pass it to the graph. So it should plot as per the values. Same as for monthly and yearly analysis.

Can anyone help me to achieve this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Sica Oerumal. J Please tried [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) it will help you a lot